# Mono WebForms: Setting default page to run when starting debugging

Tags: asp.net, mono, webforms, xsp

is it possible to set a default page to run when starting debugging? In Visual Studio you can set the default page either through the context menu in Solution Explorer or in the project properties. I did not find something like that in MonoDevelop. 
When I am starting debugging the browser will always navigate to the root of the application.

```
http://localhost:8080
```

Because there is no default page set in XSP for this application I get an error and always have to correct it manually.

```
http://localhost:8080/home.aspx
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry -- of the top of my head -- Can't you just make an index.aspx and have it go there? The last asp.net app I ran on Mono didn't have that issue, but did have index.aspx. (Realize that's not really your question, so not an answer.)

Comment: Hey, yes that would work. The manual page of xsp says that there is a configuration file xsp.exe.config. It's build like any other web.config or app.config file. In the appSettings section there is a key "MonoServerDefaultIndexFiles". There you can define the default documents XSP is looking for. These are the documents defined by default: index.aspx, Default.aspx, default.aspx, index.html and index.htm. 
There seems to be a configuration file for xsp somewhere because those default documents are working. Where is that file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a solution. I did not find the xsp.exe.config but it also works when you add the setting either globally in machine.config (residing in /etc/mono/[version]) or by creating a web.config file in your applications root. The values are comma separated.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="MonoServerDefaultIndexFiles" value="Home.aspx, home.aspx" />
</appSettings>
```

The help page http://www.mono-project.com/Config does not tell you that a appSettings section is allowed, but I think that the documentation is just incomplete. For example appSettings are used here http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET_Settings_Mapping#Inhibiting_the_settings_mapping too.